# Identify image name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called Sheets("Catalogue") that contains many pictures. I want to identify the name of the picture (e.g "Picture 15") within a certain range that i selected.
For example, lets say i select range("a1:g10"). In this range i may assume there is only one picture. I want to find out the name of this picture so that i can copy and paste to another sheet.

However i tried so many ways but i cannot get the name of the picture.

Below is one of the code i have tried:
If i remove the Range("a1:g10") this code will select all the pictures in this sheet. However that is not what i need. I must only select a picture within a specific range that i want.

```
    Set shplist = Sheets("Print_Out").Range("a1:g10")
    shplist.Shapes.SelectAll
```

Comment: It seems like a rather convoluted way of finding out the name of a picture.  If you simply click on the picture, its name will appear in the name box on the active screen.

Comment: What does *"within a certain range"* **exactly** mean? Do all corners of the picture have to be **within** this range or is it enough if one part of the image (eg. top left corner) overlays the range and another part of the image lays not within the range? Please clarify.

Comment: @kevin9999 That is true. However in my actual application, i wont be able to click on the picture. My code has to identify the name of picture (within a specific range) and then copy paste to another sheet and resize it. I have difficulty finding the name of the picture.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The picture do not need to be in all 4 corners. So long as it is within the range is fine. 

The "within a certain range" is where one of the picture will be found. In this range i need to identify the name of the picture. You may safely assume there will only be 1 picture in each selected range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will return the first shape that is found within a given range:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetFirstShapeWithinRange(ByVal Rng As Range, Optional ByVal ShapeType As MsoShapeType = 0) As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Rng.Parent
    
    Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In ws.Shapes   'loop through all shapes
        If ShapeType = 0 Or Shp.Type = ShapeType Then   'check shape type (if parameter was specified)
            If Not Intersect(Rng, ws.Range(Shp.TopLeftCell, Shp.BottomRightCell)) Is Nothing Then    'check if shape and range intersect
                Set GetFirstShapeWithinRange = Shp
                Exit Function 'exit after first shape was found.
            End If
        End If
    Next Shp
End Function
```

You can use it like below to return its name:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim Pic As Shape
    Set Pic = GetFirstShapeWithinRange(Selection, msoPicture) 'msoPicture specifies that the shape we are looking for needs to be a picture.
    
    If Not Pic Is Nothing Then 'check if a picture was found in selection
        MsgBox Shp.Name
    Else
        MsgBox "No picture found in the selected range.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

The `ShapeType` can be specified according to the [MsoShapeType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype).

It will consider the following picture to be in the selected range, because it intersects.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the code. May i clarify something? In the Function at the IF condition, why do you need to include ShapeType =0 in the IF condition? What purpose does it serve?  I also realsied if i omit '.Parent' from the Rng the code does not work. May i know why is that so?

Comment: @user13316884 The `ShapeType` argument in the function is `Optional` that means if you omit it in your function call like `Set Pic = GetFirstShapeWithinRange(Selection)` it should find **any** type of shapes not only pictures. Therefore we need that `ShapeType = 0` (which means no type specified). • `.Parent` gives you the parent object of an object. Since ranges are children of worksheets `Range.Parent` will return the worksheet where the range is located. So `Set ws = Rng.Parent` is used to get the worksheet of `Rng` because that is the worksheet we need to search for the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

### Get First Shape Name

- The function `getFirstShapeName` will return the name of the left- or top-most (`ByColumns`) shape in a range. It will consider a shape in a range only if the shape's parameter `TopLeftCell` is within the range.
- For example, If `shp1` 'starts' in `B1` and `shp2` 'starts' in `A2`, then if `ByColumns` is omitted or set to `False`, it will return `shp1`'s name (first row (`1`)). Otherwise, if `ByColumns` is set to `True`, it will return `shp2`'s name (first column (`A`)).
- The additional procedure is just an example to test the function.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Function getFirstShapeName( _
    aRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ByColumn As Boolean = False) _
As String
    
    Dim br As Double
    Dim bc As Double
    If ByColumn Then
        br = 0.0000001
        bc = 1
    Else
        br = 1
        bc = 0.00001
    End If
    
    Dim tmpValue As Double ' Temp Value
    tmpValue = aRange.Worksheet.Rows.Count + 1
    
    Dim tlc As Range       ' Top Left Cell
    Dim cShp As Shape      ' Current Shape
    Dim tmpShp As Shape    ' Temp Shape
    Dim cValue As Double   ' Current Value
    
    For Each cShp In aRange.Worksheet.Shapes
        Set tlc = cShp.TopLeftCell
        If Not Intersect(tlc, aRange) Is Nothing Then
            cValue = br * tlc.Row + bc * tlc.Column
            If cValue < tmpValue Then
                tmpValue = cValue
                Set tmpShp = cShp
            End If
        End If
    Next cShp
    
    If Not tmpShp Is Nothing Then
        getFirstShapeName = tmpShp.Name
    End If

End Function

Sub TESTgetFirstShapeName()
    Dim s As String
    s = getFirstShapeName(Sheet1.Range("A1:C10"), True)
    If Len(s) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found shape '" & s & "'."
    Else
        MsgBox "No shape found in range."
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

- This is a simplification of the above function.
- It will return the name of the first shape whose top left cell intersects with the range.

**A Simplification**

```
Function getFirstShapeNameSimple( _
    aRange As Range) _
As String
    
    Dim tlc As Range       ' Top Left Cell
    Dim cShp As Shape      ' Current Shape
    
    For Each cShp In aRange.Worksheet.Shapes
        Set tlc = cShp.TopLeftCell
        If Not Intersect(tlc, aRange) Is Nothing Then
            getFirstShapeName = cShp.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cShp
    
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tested it? For example, instead of `s = getFirstShapeName(Sheet1.Range("A1:C10"), True)` you can use `s = getFirstShapeName(Sheets("Catalogue").Range("A1:G10"))` and instead of `MsgBox "Found shape '" & s & "'."` you can use `Sheets("Catalogue").Shapes(s).Copy`.

Comment: Yes i have tested it . It works very well. But there is some part i dont understand. I do not know what is the purpose of this line onwards : 'If cValue < tmpValue Then'. Is it ok if i omit this section and immediately return cShp.Name?